# How to call column names, starting with a number, into a for() function, inside a table in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

**Explanation**

I have created a table which columns names start with numbers and I want to see that, if any of these tables has any records in it, a danger button will be shown in it.

I have tried with a `for()` function, but there is some mistake in the code below, that i can't seem to fully understand how to make it work.

**Question**

How can this be expressed in function to make it work?

**The code** (full code, updated as requested)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
     @{
         var txt = "Service";
     }

     @for (int i =30; i > 0; i--)
     {
         <td>
         @if (Model.VL.Where(u => u._@(i+txt)) == true).Any())
         {
             <span class="btn text-danger border-danger">@i</span>
         }
         else
         {
             <span class="btn border" style="min-width:50px;">...</span>
         }
      </td>
    }
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**The Db_Table**

```
public partial class ClientServiceErrors
```

{

```
[Key] public int CliErrorId { get; set; }


public datetime ErrDate { get; set; }

public int CliId { get; set; }

[Column("1Service")]
public bool _1Service { get; set; }

[Column("2Service")]
public bool _2Service { get; set; }

[Column("3Service")]
public bool _3Service { get; set; }

...

[Column("30Service")]
public bool _30Service { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CliId")]
[InverseProperty("ClientServiceErrors")]
public virtual Clients CliId { get; set; } = null!;
```

}

Comment: Not understand what you try to achieve here: `Model.VL.Where(u => u._@i) == true).Any()`, you will get a compilation error for closing bracket `)`. Column/Property name cannot be (start) with number. Will be great if you can provide sample data for `Model.VL`.

Comment: @YongShun,   I have updated (inserted the omitted part, that i thought would be useless in this case). Hope now you can better understand my situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Issues & Concerns**

1. The first statement of the `for` loop must be a statement.

   Your current code is not working as the first statement is not a statement.

**Approach 1**

1. Remove the declaration scope for `int i = 30;`
2. Declare the `i` as the first statement in the `for` loop.

```
@for (int i = 30; i > 0; i--)
{
    ...
}
```

**Approach 2**

Switch to the `while` loop.

```
@{
    int i = 30;
}

@while (i > 0)
{
    ...

    i--;
}
```

2. Your expression by building the property name programmatically is not compiled. You need *System.Linq.Expressions* to construct the LINQ expression programmatically.

Assume that the `VL` is an `IEnumerable<ClientServiceErrors>` type

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@using /*Namespace for ClientServiceErrors class*/;

var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ClientServiceErrors), "x");
var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "_" + i + txt);
var memberExpressionConversion = Expression.Convert(memberExpression, typeof(bool));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ClientServiceErrors, bool>>(memberExpressionConversion, parameterExpression);
                 
@if (Model.VL.Any(lambda.Compile()))
{
    <span class="btn text-danger border-danger">@i</span>
}
else
{
    <span class="btn border" style="min-width:50px;">...</span>
}
```

[MVC Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aspruj)

Alternatively, you can use the JSON library such as *Newtonsoft.Json* to retrieve the value from the property name programmatically.

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

@if (Model.VL.Any(x => JObject.FromObject(x)
        .SelectToken("_" + i + txt)
        .Value<bool>()))
{
    <span class="btn text-danger border-danger">@i</span>
}
else
{
    <span class="btn border" style="min-width:50px;">...</span>
}
```

Comment: Side note, it is a bad practice that declare property/column names such as `_1Service`, `_2Service`, etc. This makes logic complex when checking the value of any of those columns. And make the query performance poor as your table is getting bigger and more columns. You should consider either: 1. Store those columns as an array into a single column. 2. Consider using JSON columns to store it as a JSON object if your RDBMS is JSON-supported. 3. Normalize by moving those columns into a new table and make a 1-to-many relationship with the current table.